# python/pygame test specific key to be up

Tags: python, pygame

So i'm trying to make a topdown game and i'm having problems with player movement. When i press key [W,A,S or D] player moves that way. But i want it to keep moving as long as button is being held down. So i change [**playerMoveLeft**,  **playerMoveRight**,  **playerMoveDown** or  **playerMoveUp**] to 1

```
            if allowMovement == 1:
            if event.key == pygame.K_a:
                playerMoveLeft = 1
                print("Hello")

            if event.key == pygame.K_d:
                playerMoveRight = 1

            if event.key == pygame.K_s:
                playerMoveDown = 1

            if event.key == pygame.K_w:
                playerMoveUp = 1

            if event.key == pygame.K_LSHIFT:
                playerMoveSprint = 1
                playerSpeed = 2
```

So as long as one of playerMoves are 1 player should keep moving.
Know the problem:
When i release the key it sets all playerMoves to 0 what causes the player to stop so i'm trying to find a way to only testfor 1 specific key to be lifted up and that would set thath specific playerMove to 0.

```
        if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
        playerMoveLeft = 0
        playerMoveRight = 0
        playerMoveUp = 0
        playerMoveDown = 0
        playerMoveSprint = 0
```

Below this text there is the Full code area for player movement

```
    for event in pygame.event.get():
    if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
        valmis = True

    if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:



############################## CONTROL PLAYER ############################
        if allowMovement == 1:
            if event.key == pygame.K_a:
                playerMoveLeft = 1
                print("Hello")

            if event.key == pygame.K_d:
                playerMoveRight = 1

            if event.key == pygame.K_s:
                playerMoveDown = 1

            if event.key == pygame.K_w:
                playerMoveUp = 1

            if event.key == pygame.K_LSHIFT:
                playerMoveSprint = 1
                playerSpeed = 2

    if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
        playerMoveLeft = 0
        playerMoveRight = 0
        playerMoveUp = 0
        playerMoveDown = 0
        playerMoveSprint = 0

if playerMoveSprint == 1:
    playerSpeed = 1

if playerMoveLeft == 1:
    player_x -=(playerSpeed)
if playerMoveRight == 1:
    player_x +=(playerSpeed)
if playerMoveUp == 1:
    player_y -=(playerSpeed)
if playerMoveDown == 1:
    player_y +=(playerSpeed)
```

thanks for every one who helps!

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the problem. Your code checks if any one key was released, and then ceases all movement. If you only want to cease the movement of the corresponding key, check for `event.key` in the `if event.type == pygame.KEYUP` the same way you do in the `if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN`.

Comment: i want that if specific key is not being pressed lets say W for walking forward i wanna set ONLY playerMovementUp to be 0 not everything else too

Comment: @cmdtvt, so are you telling that the the player would moved in all direction that is East,West and South in the example you gave?If yes, that's impossible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your player can only go in one direction (up/down/left/right) at a time:

```
STANDSTILL = 0
UP = 1
RIGHT = 2
DOWN = 3
LEFT = 4
playermovement = STANDSTILL

if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
    if allowMovement == 1:
        if event.key == pygame.K_a:
            playermovement = LEFT

        if event.key == pygame.K_d:
            playermovement = RIGHT

        if event.key == pygame.K_s:
            playermovement = DOWN

        if event.key == pygame.K_w:
            playermovement = UP

        if event.key == pygame.K_LSHIFT:
            playerMoveSprint = 1
            playerSpeed = 2

if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
    if allowMovement == 1:
        if event.key == pygame.K_a or event.key == pygame.K_d or event.key == pygame.K_s or event.key == pygame.K_w:
            playermovement = STANDSTILL

        if event.key == pygame.K_LSHIFT:
            playerSpeed = 0
```

Assuming your player can move in two directions at the same time (up/down and left/right):

```
if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
    if allowMovement == 1:
        if event.key == pygame.K_a:
            playerMoveLeft = 1
            playerMoveRight = 0

        if event.key == pygame.K_d:
            playerMoveRight = 1
            playerMoveLeft = 0

        if event.key == pygame.K_s:
            playerMoveDown = 1
            playerMoveUp = 0

        if event.key == pygame.K_w:
            playerMoveUp = 1
            playerMoveDown = 0

        if event.key == pygame.K_LSHIFT:
            playerMoveSprint = 1
            playerSpeed = 2

if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
    if allowMovement == 1:
        if event.key == pygame.K_a:
            playerMoveLeft = 0

        if event.key == pygame.K_d:
            playerMoveRight = 0

        if event.key == pygame.K_s:
            playerMoveDown = 0

        if event.key == pygame.K_w:
            playerMoveUp = 0

        if event.key == pygame.K_LSHIFT:
            playerSpeed = 0
```

It makes no sense to allow the player figure to move left *and* right at the same time, so set the opposite direction to zero whenever the player presses the button in one of these directions (same for up/down).

Comment: Thank you that was the thing i was missing!